# Why does the Silhouette_score require labels as input?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Why is it wrong to think that it only needs the data since it: "outputs a measure of how similar an object is to its own cluster (cohesion) compared to other clusters (separation)."

However, I also need to input the labels (which the function itself computes); so, why are the labels necessary to input?

Answer (score 1):

> how similar an object is to **its own cluster**

In order to compute the silhouette, you need to know to which cluster your samples belong.

Also:

> The Silhouette Coefficient is calculated using the mean intra-cluster distance (`a`) and the mean nearest-cluster distance (`b`) for each sample. The Silhouette Coefficient for a sample is `(b - a) / max(a, b)`. To clarify, `b` is the distance between a sample and the nearest cluster that the sample is not a part of.

You need the labels to know what "intra-cluster" and "nearest-cluster" mean.

Answer (score 1):

`Silhouette_score` is a metric for clustering quality, not a clustering algorithm. It considers both the inter-class and intra-class distance.

For that calculation to happen, you need to supply both the data and target labels (estimated by unsupervised methods like `K-means`).